# iOS 17: How to use `HKWorkoutBuilder` inside unit tests

Tags: swift, xcode, healthkit

With iOS 17 creation of `HKWorkout` is deprecated via its init functions and the recommendation is to use `HKWorkoutBuilder`:
[image]

The problem is that I am creating this `HKWorkout` object inside unit tests in order to test a service that works with such objects. And `HKWorkoutBuilder` requires a `HKHealthStore` which itself requires to be authenticated to be able to create `HKWorkoutActivity` instances, like it would be when an app is running. But since the unit tests cannot accept the request on the `HKHealthStore` I am not sure if using `HKWorkoutBuilder` inside unit tests is possible.

Any ideas on how to proceed with creating `HKWorkout` for unit test purposes?

Comment: I've tried to inherit HKHealthStore and override all of its methods, but still, store requires authorization.